# How to find the gap sequence in non identity column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have more than ten thousand rows in a table like below, and I want find out the missing gaps in the sequence number in that list

```
CI-480-1617
CI-481-1617
CI-482-1617
CI-483-1617
CI-484-1617
CI-485-1617
CI-486-1617
CI-487-1617
CW-095-1617
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Ideally you should have the sequence number as completely separate numeric column.  If you would have the need to do this often, then this is a change worth making.

Comment: How does your table looks like ? How does your data looks like ?

Comment: What is the gap here - is it gaps in the middle number, partitioned by the first and last component? Please give an example of what a gap looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data, I cannot test the solution, but something like this might help you in the current situation:

```
WITH CTE AS -- end previous statement with semi colon
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING (ColumnA, 4,3) AS SeqNumb, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING (ColumnA, 4,3) ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNumb
FROM TableA
)

SELECT C.*, C2.RowNumb - C.RowNumb AS Gap
FROM CTE AS C
LEFT JOIN CTE AS C2 ON C.RowNumb = C2.RowNumb - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on some assumptions and may help you:

- the first part of every row is SECTION
- the second part of every row is ID

**Table creation:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Gaps] (
    [Text] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT [dbo].[Gaps] ([Text])
VALUES 
    ('CI-480-1617'),
    ('CI-481-1617'),
    ('CI-482-1617'),
    ('CI-483-1617'),
    ('CI-484-1617'),
    ('CI-485-1617'),
    ('CI-486-1617'),
    ('CI-487-1617'),
    ('CW-095-1617');
```

**Finding gaps:**

```
WITH IDS (Section, Nmr) AS (
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING([Text], 1, CHARINDEX('-', [Text]) - 1),
        CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING([Text], CHARINDEX('-', [Text]) + 1, CHARINDEX('-', [Text], CHARINDEX('|', [Text]))))
    FROM Gaps
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT SUBSTRING([Text], 1, CHARINDEX('-', [Text]) - 1),
        0
    FROM Gaps
    -- Uncomment next lines if you want to get the gap to some MAX value
    --UNION ALL
    --SELECT 
    --  DISTINCT SUBSTRING([Text], 1, CHARINDEX('-', [Text]) - 1),
    --  1000
    --FROM Gaps
)
SELECT Section, StartNmr = cur + 1, EndNmr = nxt - 1
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Section, 
        cur = Nmr, 
        nxt = (
            SELECT MIN(B.Nmr)
            FROM IDS AS B
            WHERE B.Section = A.Section AND B.Nmr > A.Nmr
        )
    FROM IDS AS A
) AS D
WHERE nxt - cur > 1
ORDER BY Section, StartNmr
```

**Output (without MAX value):**

```
-----------------------
Section  StartNmr  EndNmr
-----------------------
CI       1         479
CW       1         94
```

**Output (with MAX value):**

```
-----------------------
Section  StartNmr  EndNmr
-----------------------
CI       1         479
CI       488       999
CW       1         94
CW       96        999
```